# google-maps-api-3 in div with position:fixed scroll

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get google-maps in div with position:fixed. The problem is when i scroll in the body the fixed div is not redrawn and the map scrolls along side the body, when i then scroll in the div not only the map but everything else is bugging out!

the div has the following css

```
.bs-docs-sidenav {
width: 48%;
top: 20px;
height:250px;
position:fixed;
background-color:yellow;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

I made a look at this jsfiddle and you will understand what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/PdqME/

The problem seems to be isolated to **Chrome**.